# Add Click event to my dynamically created Xaml Button

Tags: c#, xaml

I'm currently writing a function that creates button in XAML (on runtime) according to JSON information that is received from an API call in C#.

I currently have the following code:

```
Button downloadButton = new Button();
downloadButton.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(DownloadContent);
```

But I get the following error:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
> property 'Mainwindow.DownloadContent(object, RoutedEventArgs)'

I've tried changing it to `downloadButton.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(this, DownloadContent);` but that gives me the error:

> `Keyword 'this' is not valid in a static property, static method, or static field initializer`

For reference this is what `DownloadContent` looks like

```
private void DownloadContent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("API-URL"), contentZip);
    webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(InstallContent);        
}
```

This is what I want the button to look like (skipping the other stuff like background color, etc.)

```
<Button Name="Downloadbutton" 
  Content="Download"
  Click="DownloadContent"
</Button>
```

Am I missing something as why I get this Error and how could I fix it?

**EDIT**

The Installcontent function looks like this:

```
private void InstallContent(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(contentZip, contentPath, true);
    File.Delete(contentZip);
    writeJsonData(DLCbuttonTag);
    Downloadbutton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    Uninstallbutton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

The function that creates the button:

```
public static void getContentList()
        {
        string jsonString = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\stage\OneDrive\Documenten\ContentInfo.json")
        ContentList contentList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ContentList>(jsonString);;

            for (int i = 0; i < contentList.Content.Count; i++)
            {
                    StackPanel dynamicStackPanel = new StackPanel();
                    dynamicStackPanel.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
                    dynamicStackPanel.Background = Brushes.Transparent;
                    
                    Button downloadButton = new Button();
                    downloadButton.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(DownloadContent);
                    dynamicStackPanel.Children.Add(downloadButton);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `getContentList` is declared as `static`. You try to reference the method `DownloadContent` which is an instance method. Remove the `static` from `getContentList` to fix the error.

The reason for the error is that static methods cannot access instance members. Static members do not run in the context of a particular instance, but in the context of the type itself. While in the case of WPF there most likely is no other instance of your page, in theory there could be many. The static method would not know which instance to pick, hence the error.

See this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members) for details on static members.

As a sidenote: in C#, methods are usually started with a capital letter (Pascal casing) regardless of their access modifier. So `getContentList` would be `GetContentList`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But how would I remove the `static` from `Installcontent`?

I've added the `this` in front of `Installcontent` but this did not change anything

Comment: Can you add the declaration of `InstallContent` to your question?

Comment: I've added it to the question

Comment: Thank you - can you also add the declaration of the method that contains `downloadButton.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(DownloadContent);`? This is the method that might be static.

Comment: I've added the function that goes through the Json data and creates a button for each array/list element. Hopefully thats what you needed?

Comment: `getContentList` is marked as static. You need to make this to an instance-method by removing `static`.